# MySQL - Round seconds to nearest half minute

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to round the mysql table field to next nearest half minute.Field contain only seconds like 22,44,121 But looks like my logic is wrong. Can someone help me. Ex:

```
22 seconds would be .5 minutes
35 seconds would be 1 minutes
68 seconds would be 1.5 minutes
121 seconds would be 2.5 minutes
```

here my solution

```
select seconds_field,CEILING(seconds_field /60 * 30) as formatted_second_fields from table
```

sample values for seconds_fields

```
22
44
121
1243
364
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to explain what you want is that there is a ceiling event which should happen for every 30 second interval, and furthermore each interval contributes to one half of a minute.  This leads to the following query:

```
SELECT
    seconds_field,
    CEILING(seconds_field / 30) / 2 AS formatted_second_fields
FROM yourTable;
```

## Demo